# How to enable sql developer (oracle) debug option

Tags: oracle, debugging

I have a package that consists of functions and procedure. I nee d to run that package in debug mode. I can set breakpoint in the functions or procedures. But if I want to debug the package that is not working. The run option is showing as disable. How can I make that work.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Your user needs to have debug permission on the DB SCHEMA. Contact the dba request granting of `DEBUG CONNECT SESSION` privilege.

Comment: grant debug connect session to (user); Run this sql in system user. Then you can start to debug your package. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to your opened connection, open your package, then you will be able to debug it.

[image]